# Automatically detect when HDMI is plugged in

Tags: linux, bash, audio, hdmi

Sometimes I connect my laptop to my TV over HDMI to have a bigger screen. Unfortunately, it doesn't automatically switch the audio output, so I have to do that myself every single time I plug or unplug it, with either of those two, to have the sound come from where I want it to come from.

- `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:hdmi-stereo-extra1`
- `pacmd set-card-profile 0 output:analog-stereo+input:analog-stereo`

Is there any way to detect if HDMI is plugged in, or at least if a change has occurred? Thanks!

Linux Mint 18.2 Xfce x64, Asus P756U

Comment: This Q is not about programming as defined for StackOverflow. It **may** be more appropriate on https://superuser.com OR https://unix.stackexchange.com . Use the `flag` link at the bottom of your Q and ask the moderator to move it. Please don't post the same Q on 2 different sites. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic ,  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve before posting more Qs here.Good Luck

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I am using two different ways to determine if HDMI is plugged in:

a) Using xrandr
A simple xrandr will report your hdmi monitor as connected
To use this in a script you can do something like:

```
hdmi_active=$(xrandr |grep ' connected' |grep 'HDMI' |awk '{print $1}')
```

Above will return the connected hdmi port (i.e HDMI-1) or will return nothing if no HDMI is connected.

You can then use something like

```
[[ ! -z "$hdmi_active" ]] && do_your_stuff
```

`z` becomes `true` if `$hdmi_active` is not set . `! z` reverts this behavior and returns `true` if hdmi_active has a value = hdmi is connected

b) Using the HDMI status file:

```
$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status
```

This returns connected / disconnected for your hdmi ports:

```
$ cat /sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status
disconnected
disconnected
```

You can then test against that result with something like:

```
hdmi_active="$(cat /sys/class/drm/card0/*HDMI*/status |grep '^connected')" #Using ^ we avoind matching disconnected from the regex match, since ^ in an anchor to the beginning of the line
[[ ! -z "$hdmi_active" ]] && do_your_stuff #hdmi is active
```

Comment: What is the status if the HDMI cable is plugged in to the laptop, but on the screen/TV another HDMI input is selected? I'm wondering if I can detect input change on the screen.

Comment: I tell you know. It does not work, and as of now, it is an unsolved problem.

Comment: @JuanseCora When you say "it does not work" you refer to my solution or to the question posted by nagy.zsolt.hun ?

Comment: @GeorgeVasiliou I refer to nagy.zsolt.hun comment in which he asks if it can detect input change on the scrren.